# Postsharp OnException Aspect not Working as Expected

Tags: c#, .net, postsharp

I have the following custom aspect, and have tried applying it at project and class level. In all cases, even an intentional divide by zero, the `OnException` method is never called. What am I doing wrong?

```
[Serializable]
public class AutoLogExceptionsAspect : OnExceptionAspect
{
  public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
  {
    AutoLogExceptionEventSource.Log.AutoLogException(args.Exception.GetType().Name, args.Exception.Message, args.Exception.StackTrace);
    args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;
  }

  public override Type GetExceptionType(MethodBase targetMethod)
  {
    return typeof(Exception);
  }
}
```

I have tried this decoration on a class:

```
[AutoLogExceptionsAspect]
public partial class App : Application
```

and this one on the project:

```
[assembly: AutoLogExceptionsAspect]
```

Comment: The GetExceptionType override is redundant, as it will catch `Exception` anyway. Show us how you decorated your class / project

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, please see modified question.

Comment: Try `[assembly: YourNamespace.AutoLogExceptionsAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "YourNamespace.*")]`

Comment: No difference I'm afraid.

Comment: When you say "intentional divide by zero", you do mean integer divide by zero, correct?

Comment: Correct. It now picks it up though, something came right with the PostSharp role in the build process.

Comment: Are you sure that your assembly is 'postharped'? Make sure your aspect is in fact weaved in. Take some reflector tool, dissasemble your compiled dll and check if the postsharp code is there. You could use ILSpy for example.

Comment: Are you missing this line: base.OnException(args); at the end of your public override void OnException() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO AutoLogExceptionsAspect is not related to onexception aspect (or at least is not mandatory).

Usually when Exception (or other "methods" aspects attributes) are not called, it is because there was a problem in build chain at PostSharp call time.

Please get sure if Postsharp is up and running on build machines, and Postsharp is enabled in project properties (for example, no "SkipPostSharp" switch in properties on assemblies which needs PostSharp to be processed). If not attributes won't be executed.

Comment: It somehow came right itself, but it was a build time issue. Suddenly one day PostSharp produced a build error executing one of its tools, and that highlighted a seemingly unrelated problem which I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If Postsharp licence is not valid or expired, It's skipping OnException method in your class. Updating Postsharp with a valid licence number solved my issue.